# And yet another “Cannot Find Symbol Variable DaggerAppComponent”

Tags: android-studio, dagger-2

I'm trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://proandroiddev.com/mvvm-architecture-viewmodel-and-livedata-part-2-di-1a6b1f96d84b) in my own project, but no matter what I do, I will always get

> “Cannot Find Symbol Variable DaggerAppComponent”

I've tried all the solutions posted here in StackOverflow, invalidate the cache, clean and rebuild many times but the error still persist. Here's my build.gradle

```
project.ext {
    appcompat = "26.1.0"
    arch = "1.1.0"
    retrofit = "2.0.2"
    constraintLayout = "1.0.2"
    daggerVer = "2.15"
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.imincode.sps"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$project.daggerVer"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$project.daggerVer"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$project.daggerVer"

    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVer"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVer"

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$project.appcompat"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$project.constraintLayout"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$project.retrofit"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$project.retrofit"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$project.arch"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$project.arch"
}
```

And here's the class which tries to implement DaggerAppComponent

```
public class AppInjector {
    private AppInjector(){}

    public static void init(SPSApplication spsApplication){    
        DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(spsApplication).build().inject(spsApplication);
    }
}
```

Here's my AppModule

```
@Module(subcomponents = ViewModelSubComponent.class)
class AppModule {
    @Singleton @Provides
    WebService provideWebService(){
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(WebService.SERVER_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(WebService.class);
    }

    @Singleton @Provides
    ViewModelProvider.Factory provideViewModelFactory(ViewModelSubComponent.Builder viewModelSubComponent){
        return new ProjectViewModelFactory(viewModelSubComponent.build());
    }
}
```

And SubComponent

```
@Subcomponent
public interface ViewModelSubComponent {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder{
        ViewModelSubComponent build();
    }

    LoginViewModel loginViewModel();
}
```

If it helps, I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1 and below is how I structure my codes..

[image]

Comment: Can you show your module and component classes?

Comment: @Héctor what do you mean by show my module and component classes here? Do the creation of classes will effect the ability of Dagger to generate DaggerAppComponent ?

Comment: I mean, classes annotated with "@Module" and "@Component"

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Héctor. I've added my "@Module" and "@SubComponent" code. I don't have any "@Component"

Comment: Did you managed to resolve your issue with Dagger2?@imin